# Passing input from HTML to JS

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

So I'm working on a Chrome extension to help me on my job. I need to autocomplete some fields but for some reason I cant pass the info from HTML to the .js file.
I have a list for the input and a script to make you able to search among any part of the given words. For example, if you type 'la' it should suggest New Zealand, England and Ireland.
Well, when I run the html to test it does not work. Could you give me some light on this?

Thank you!

HTML

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <input data-list="Brazil, United States, New Zealand, Canada, England, Ireland" 

data-multiple />
    <script src="popup.js" async></script
</body>

</html>
```

.JS file

```
new Autocomplete('input[data-multiple]', {
    filter: function(text, input) {
        return Autocomplete.FILTER_CONTAINS(text, input.match(/[^,]*$/)[0]);
    },

    replace: function(text) {
        var before = this.input.value.match(/^.+,\s*|/)[0];
        this.input.value = before + text + ", ";
    }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when I run the html to test it does not work"?

Comment: Before using it as a Chrome extension, I can just execute the html file. Well, it only shows the place to type any text but it does not suggest as it should ;-)

Comment: Why do you expect `Autocomplete` to be available? It's not something standard. You either are not showing the full code or not even trying to debug (which would tell you that `Autocomplete` is not defined).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing angle bracket:

`<script src="popup.js" async></script`

add the bracket:

`<script src="popup.js" async></script>`

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a new datalist element now.  You should try to see if you can get this to work for you.

```
<input list="keys" />
<datalist id="keys">
  <option value="Home">
  <option value="Work">
  <option value="Car">
</datalist>
```

As you type, the datalist will automatically do the suggestions for you, based on the elements found within the list.